# How many times does client fetch the consensus file from directory authorities?

Tags: directory, client, consensus

I am wondering that how many times a client "talks" to Directory Server (say, it can be a hard-coded Directory Authority Server, or just a normal Directory Server) to fetch the consensus file, knowing that the consensus file is changed, and redistributed among directory servers every one hour?

In other words, how frequent does a client fetch consensus data from Directory Server, or just once at the beginning time when starting Tor Browser? Lets assume that this client continuously uses Tor for more than 1 hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see it the answer is in the source code. ;-)

The file [`main.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/main.c) has a function [`run_scheduled_events`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/main.c#n1220). The comment to this function says:

> Perform regular maintenance tasks.  This function gets run once per second by `second_elapsed_callback()`.

Within the source code there is a list of things which this function does. As far as I see it item [2c](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/main.c#n1511) deals with downloading the networkstatus:

> 2c. Every minute (or every second if TestingTorNetwork), check whether we want to download any networkstatus documents.

The code itself is:

```
#define networkstatus_dl_check_interval(o) ((o)->TestingTorNetwork ? 1 : 60)

if (!should_delay_dir_fetches(options, NULL) &&
    time_to_download_networkstatus < now) {
  time_to_download_networkstatus =
    now + networkstatus_dl_check_interval(options);
  update_networkstatus_downloads(now);
}
```

So it looks at [`should_delay_dir_fetches` in `networkstatus.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/networkstatus.c#n918). If your network is enabled and you have running bridges/pluggable transports (in case you set it) all is fine. Furthermore it checks if a specific timer is less than the current time. If this is true, the timer is updated (current time plus 60 seconds) and `update_networkstatus_downloads` is called which itself calls `update_consensus_networkstatus_downloads`. This function takes care about the actual downloading.

The function is defined at [line 733 in `networkstatus.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/networkstatus.c#n733). It has a bit more logic inside. However as far as I see it, it waits until the current consensus is older than the current time. If this happens a new document is fetched.

You can also set logging at info level and will find lines like the following:

> Jan 28 18:21:51.000 [info] update_consensus_networkstatus_downloads(): Launching microdesc networkstatus consensus download.
>   Jan 28 19:36:04.000 [info] update_consensus_networkstatus_downloads(): Launching microdesc networkstatus consensus download.

Summary: Every minute it is checked if the consensus document is too old. If it is older than the current time a new one will be fetched.

Comment: Dear Jens, thank you so much for your informative Answer. I think it's probably what I am really looking for. However, I will need to figure it out a little bit to get the most precise answer, cos you interpreted from the source code that :"every 60 seconds is an attempt to download new documents", but to the best of my knowledge, the consensus file is only regenerated every one hour, as I asked here: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/how-can-i-get-consensus-data-from-directory-authority-servers-for-research-purpo
So does "1download/60s" will add more load to the directory servers?

Comment: @Windy: I missed a point and have corrected my first answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Dear Jens, that was a wonderful answer. Thanks to your dedicated and comprehensive explanation, I am quite clear now about the internal operating mechanism of the source code. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

From what I gathered, I have not found anything that point that a client periodically fetch the consensus file. On the other hand, consensus files do expire, and when that happens the client will request the latest version.

If you set **TestingTorNetwork** in *torrc* to **1**, one of the properties tested will be the frequency of fetching the consensus file. The following values will be tested for both clients and servers:

`TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 60
TestingClientConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 60`

Comment: Dear Linostar. Thank you so much for your prompt explanation. So, do you have any idea about how long a consensus will expire, or it will just expire when a new consensus is available to download?
Btw, thank you so much for your precious hint, I found some helpful definition here https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#TestingTorNetwork

And here as well, although I still cannot clearly understand some terminologies in this Trac#ticket:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13976

Comment: As per definition of Tor metrics, the consensus is voted on by directory authorities once per hour. I guess that means the expiry duration is also 1 hour.